# SQL error on insert

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with the following SQL statement?

```
INSERT INTO thread (deleted) 
VALUES ('2009-01-02 17:41:02') 
WHERE thread.id = 28
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE thread.id = 28' at line 3

**EDIT: I'm such an Idiot... UPDATE!!!**

Thank you.

Comment: The `INSERT` statement inserts an entirely new row into your database. It looks like you want to `UPDATE` a current row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE thread 
   SET deleted = TIMESTAMP '2009-01-02 17:41:02'
 WHERE id = 28;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `where` in an `insert...values...` statement. What are you trying to do?